# Swift signal SIGABRT error

Tags: swift, core-data, sigabrt

Here's the code:

```
 func setupData() {

    clearData()

    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    if let context = delegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext {



        let mark = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Friend", into: context) as! Friend
        mark.name = "Vuyo Nkabinde"
        mark.profileImageName = "zuckprofile"


        let message = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Message", into: context) as! Message
        message.friend = mark
        message.text = "Hello, my name is Mark. Nice to meet you..."
        message.date = NSDate()

        let steve = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Friend", into: context) as! Friend
        steve.name = "Steve Jobs"
        steve.profileImageName = "steve_profile"

        let messagesSteve = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Message", into: context) as! Message
        messagesSteve.friend = steve
        messagesSteve.text = "Code is the most innovative company I have ever seen..."
        messagesSteve.date = NSDate()

        do {
        try(context.save())
        } catch let err {
            print(err)

        }

    }
```

My issue is with the  `let mark = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Friend", into: context) as! Friend` line, it was written in swift 2 and I changed all the code to swift 3 but this particular line gives me a signal SIGABRT error.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the interface for accessing managed objects changed from swift2 to swift3. As explained in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905821/how-to-insert-new-data-to-entity-in-swift3), looks like in your case you need:

```
 let mark = Friend(context: context)
 mark.name = "Vuyo Nkabinde"
 mark.profileImageName = "zuckprofile"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my Swift 3.0 app:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Friend", in: context)
let mark = Friend(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
mark.name = "Vuyo Nkabinde"
mark.profileImageName = "zuckprofile"

[etc...]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this in Swift 3:

```
let employee = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Friend", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Friend
```

Please check syntax for [Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html), It is like above.

Hope is helps